# Cron Jobs on Heroku

Tags: cron, heroku

According to the Heroku docs:

Cron jobs execute based on when you enable the add-on

However, I enabled the cron add on at 8pm two nights ago and the cron job did not run at 8pm last night. At 3pm today, I ran "heroku cron" and the job kicked off without any issue.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Does running "heroku cron" mean it will run at 3pm every day from now on? I am using the daily cron job add on and not the hourly addon.

Thanks,
  gearoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see when your cron job is scheduled by looking at your app's Cron add-on on the web interface.

The [Heroku Backup Task](https://github.com/joemsak/heroku_backup_task) gem makes it really easy automatically back up with a cron job.

Heroku's native automatic backups add-on is in private beta now, so hopefully it'll be released soon: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Answer (score 4):

You do not need an addon to run chronic tasks on Heroku.

Install the gem

```
 gem install rufus-scheduler
```

Make sure you include the gem in bundler or however you are including it.

Then you need to create a file called `task_scheduler.rb` and stick this in you `initializers` directory.

```
 require 'rufus/scheduler'
 scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

 scheduler.every '1s' do

      puts "Test!"      
      #do something here

 end
```

If you have any trouble you can see this blog post:

http://intridea.com/2009/2/13/dead-simple-task-scheduling-in-rails?blog=company

Comment: Does this remove the need for Delayed Jobs too?

Comment: Be careful--if I'm not mistaken, Heroku spins down idle apps after a certain period of inactivity. If you don't get a lot of traffic you might miss some scheduled tasks.

Comment: Checkout this blog post I wrote to hack that problem:  http://codeglot.com/posts/25-simple_way_to_keep_smaller_apps_loaded_on_herkou